# new Proxy(new Map(), {}).values

Tags: javascript

How can I Proxy a Map, and then access the `values` of the proxied map?

Here is the code I am attempting:

```
const things = new Proxy(new Map(), {
  set(t, k, v) {
    console.log(t, k, v);
    Reflect.set(t, k, v);
  }
});

things['foo'] = 'bar'
// console log: Map(0) {} "foo" "bar"

console.log(things['foo']);
// console log: "bar"

things.values()
Uncaught TypeError: Method Map.prototype.values called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
    at Proxy.values (native)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that `Map` methods complain if its *thisArg* is not an actual `Map` object. One solution would be to add a `get` to the proxy that checks if the property being fetched is a function, and if so, it returns a function that calls the requested function using the original, non-Proxy object.

```
const things = new Proxy(new Map(), {
  set(t, k, v) {
    console.log(t, k, v);
    Reflect.set(t, k, v);
  },
  get(t, k) {
    if (typeof t[k] === "function") {
      return (...args) => Reflect.apply(t[k], t, args)
    }
    return t[k];
  }
});
```

One potential down-side to this is that the function returned will be effectively bound to the original map. Probably not an issue for most cases, but it will render calls like `things.values.call(someOtherMap)` useless. There are probably ways to work around this if it's an issue.

Comment: Another downside is that the Map can no longer store functions as keys, which the native Map is able to do.

Comment: Actually it seems that is not a problem. `t[k]` accesses the map's prototype methods, and `t.get(k)` accesses the values by key.

Comment: It could be a problem if the values are functions that need to have their *thisArg* set to a specific value.

Comment: Although this has pitfalls for the general use, this solution does meet my specific needs. Accepting this answer. Thanks.